# Left outer join of 3 tables

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to get the count of distinct people of the shaded region.

Table structure is as follows:

```
    customer       key
    A234            1
    A345            4
    A12             5
    A989            6
```

[image]

HIVE Query:

```
    select count(distinct(a.customer)) 
    from (
        select *
         from cust
         where key in (1,2,3)) c 
    left outer join (
        select *
         from cust
         where key in (4,5)) a on a.customer= c.customer where c.customer is null
         join
            (select *
             from cust
             where key in (6,7,8,9)) d on c.customer = d.customer and d.customer is null;
```

Error:

missing EOF at 'join' near 'null'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax problem because `where` follows the `from` clause, and a given `select` has only one `where`.

I would just use `group by` and `having`.  To get the customers:

```
select c.customer
from cust c
group by c.customer
having sum(case when key in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when key in (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

You can then count them with a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select c.customer
      from cust c
      group by c.customer
      having sum(case when key in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when key in (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
    ) c
```

Comment: Thanks, For getting the data in intersection of all three circles, is this the right way to write the query:

         select count(*)
         from (select c.customer
               from cust c
               group by c.customer
               having sum(case when key in (1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
             ) c